# Java Standard On Result Of Casting A Double To An Int

Tags: java, java-8, standards, standards-compliance

Say I have the following...

```
double d = 1.6;
int q = ( ( int ) d );
```

Will this always drop the just decimal point according to the Java standard, or could it round up or down ***according to the standard*** (Which more or less exists)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will drop the decimal point. That means it will round *towards zero*, so it will round down if it is positive, but it will round up if it is negative.

See [§5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) in the JLS:

> Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode ([§4.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)).

Answer (score 0):

Casting a `double` to an `int` always floors the value to greatest integer less than it, but try this:

```
int q = (int) Math.round(d); // rounded instead of floored
```